# Python Scikit - bad input shape when calling sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to build a PRC (precision-recall curve) for a `CatBoostClassifier`.

But when I'm calling `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_score)` I'm getting `ValueError: bad input shape (11912, 2)`.

What could be wrong with my current approach? And what do I need to fix here to provide a correct shape?

```
import sklearn 
from sklearn import metrics 
y_score = model.predict_proba(X_test) 
prc_auc = sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_score)
```

*//Here is how I build a model*

```
model = CatBoostClassifier( 
iterations=50, 
random_seed=63, 
learning_rate=0.15, 
custom_loss=['Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall', 'AUC']
) 

model.fit( 
X_train, y_train, 
cat_features=cat_features, 
eval_set=(X_test, y_test), 
verbose=10, 
plot=True 
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial answer is that `CatBoostClassifier.model.predict_proba` returns a 2d array; `sklearn.model.precision_recall_curve` requires a 1d array (or a 2d array with one column, whichever).

The documentation for `CatBoostClassifier` says that `predict_proba()` returns `numpy.array`, and provides no other information about this method. So I hate the documentation for this package now.

Walking through some poorly-commented code gets me to:

```
    if prediction_type == 'Probability':
        predictions = np.transpose([1 - predictions, predictions])
        return predictions
```

I'm guessing that column 0 is the probability of class 0, and column 1 is the probability of class 1. So pick whichever of those things your test aligns with and use that column only.

```
prc_auc = sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_score[:, 1])
```